# Proper use of std::sort in c ++

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

for example I have a string data with the following contents

```
std :: string words {"armando dippet"};
```

if using

`words.begin () / end ()` then it works,

but if

`std :: string words [] {"gandalf", '"harry", "malfoy", "ron"}`

using

`std::sort(words.begin () / end ())`

does not work, but must be changed to

`std :: sort (std :: begin (words), std :: end (words))`

or

`std :: sort (words, words + sizeof ( words) / sizeof (words [0]))`

in order to run, then I switched to dynamic strings

`std :: string * words {new std :: string [2] {"hermione", "aziz"}}`

using

`std::sort(std :: begin (words) / end (words))`

didn't work, using

`std::sort(words-> begin () words -> end ())`

is successful but the result is not suitable, using

`std :: sort (words, words + sizeof (words) / sizeof (words [0]))`

is successful

To be honest, I'm confused about the use of sort

Comment: It works when you give it proper iterators and doesn't when you don't. Where's the confusion?

Comment: Your problems are not really about `std::sort`. You don't seem to understand arrays and memory allocation, so you are calling the wrong combinations of functions for different things. You could look at the SO [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191) or find some [online tutorials](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/61-arrays-part-i/).

Comment: I don't think your final example does what you think it does. On most platforms `sizeof (std::string *) / sizeof (std::string)` results in 0

Comment: what do you actaully expect `words.begin () / end ()` to mean? There is some similarity to `sizeof (words) / sizeof (words [0])` (both have a `/`) but it isnt really clear what you think it does

Comment: Please format your code so it's all colorful like in the answers. We are not used to read code that is just 2 colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going backwards

```
std::string * dynamic_length {new std :: string [2] {"hermione", "aziz"}};
```

Pointers are not arrays. They don't have a length, so you will have to record that elsewhere.

```
std::sort(dynamic_length, dynamic_length + 2);
```

Arrays lack methods. They are *only* an contiguous sequence of values. The array type holds the length.

```
std::string static_length[] {"gandalf", '"harry", "malfoy", "ron"}; // declares a std::string[4]
```

There is an implicit conversion from array to pointer.

```
std::sort(static_length, static_length + 4);
```

`std` has a pair of function templates that operate on arrays (and have other overloads)

```
std::sort(std::begin(static_length), std::end(static_length));
```

`begin` simply does the array to pointer conversion. `end` additionally adds the length, taken from the type.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T * end(T(&arr)[N]) // this is the syntax for passing an array reference
{ return arr + N; }
```

What you should be using is an actual container, such as `std::vector<std::string>`

```
std::vector<std::string> words {"gandalf", '"harry", "malfoy", "ron"};
```

This has members `begin` and `end`, overloads for the free function `begin` and `end`, and others

```
std::sort(words.begin(), words.end()); // member
std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words)); // free function
std::sort(words.data(), words.data() + words.size()); // vector converts to pointer too
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> std :: string * words {new std :: string [2] {"hermione", "aziz"}}
> std :: sort (words, words + sizeof (words) / sizeof (words [0]))
> ```
>
> is successful

It is "successful" in the sense that the types of the arguments are iterators, and therefore well-formed.

But the pointer arithmetic on your end pointer is wrong and depending on the size of `std::string` it could go beyond the array resulting in undefined behaviour (in general case; not necessarily in this one), or it could result to the beginning and nothing is sorted, or anything in between. In short, the calculation is no related to the length of the array in any way.

Here is a correct version:

```
std::sort(words, words + 2);
```

---

P.S. Avoid using owning bare pointers.

Comment: here's my resource https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/comment-page-9/#comment-484071, your solution std::sort(words, words + 2) is very enlightening